# Is there any way to use a ref class in a value type class?

Tags: windows, c++-cli

I've just got into to managed c++. I've created a class called Player which type is value. Now within this class I need to use some sort of dynamic array. I've tried using System List but the visual studio gives me an error that I can not use a ref class in a value class. What is this error? What can I use?

```
using namespace System;
using namespace Collections;
using namespace Generic;

public value class Player
{
     // other codes

     List<int> MyItems  // Gives error : Can not use ref class

     // other codes
};
```

Comment: @herohuyongtao I doubt he is actually using *managed c++*, but is really using C++/CLI.

Comment: What compiler are you using, and is it really C++/CLI or managed C++? Managed C++ is older and deprecated.

Comment: Also, are you sure you really need `Player` as a value type?

Comment: Well I really can't tell what is this called. Actually I am trying to code in visual c++ for a windows form application. @crashmstr

Comment: So far, I guess yeah @crashmstr

Comment: @crashmstr More like *`managed c++`* or *`C#`* to me.

Comment: @herohuyongtao nope, does not look like [managed c++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_Extensions_for_C%2B%2B) to me. Looks like [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) which was introduced in Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a problem, a value class can contain any reference type reference.  What you cannot do is arbitrarily omit the ^ hat, the member must be a reference as demanded by .NET since the object is always allocated on the heap.  The compile error you get is a bit clumsy, perhaps.  This compiles fine:

```
public value class Player {
    List<int>^ list;             // Note: ^ required.
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I don't think you need to use a `value` class here. You can read up on them if you wish ([Value Class in C++/CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274772/value-class-in-c-cli), [C++/CLI: Value Class Types](http://www.drdobbs.com/ccli-value-class-types/184401955))

Instead, just make `Player` a reference type. This is what *most* user classes should be. The main difference is that you allocate with `gcnew`, and the garbage collector will do the cleanup. You also need to use the `^` to indicate a reference. In your code, this is missing for the `List` member.

```
public ref class Player
{
    // other codes

    List<int>^ MyItems;

    // other codes
};

void use()
{
    Player^ p = gcnew Player();
    //use p, but make sure MyItems gets allocated with `gcnew`
    //somewhere as well!
}
```